# How to get rid of number suffix in rsyslog's own 'programname' ang 'syslogtag' property

Tags: logs, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm forwarding logs from local rsyslogs to central rsyslog and then to Elasticsearch. Everything works fine, but entries with severity `error` generated by rsyslog itself have property `programname` like `rsyslog-2222` or `rsyslog-2039` which disrupts aggregation in Elasticsearch. Can't find any info what those numbers are. They are not random and they are not PIDs for sure.

Why rsyslog does this?

Can those numbers be removed on rsyslog level?

Example logs:

```
2019-08-07T19:48:00+02:00 rsyslogd-2039 err     Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
2019-08-07T19:48:00+02:00 rsyslogd-2007 warning action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Wed Aug  7 19:48:30 2019 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
2019-08-07T19:00:39+02:00 rsyslogd-2222 err     command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
2019-08-07T19:00:39+02:00 rsyslogd-2039 err     Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
2019-08-07T19:00:39+02:00 rsyslogd-2007 warning action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Wed Aug  7 19:01:09 2019 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

Comment: Please add to your post an example of the error message. You can replace with x any information you might think is confidential, like IP addresses etc.

Comment: @meuh, I've added to the question some example entries. Non-warn/err entries have `rsyslog` _programname_. I've just found a solution for this. Look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `programname` is created by parsing `syslogtag`. It looks like `syslogtag` is not super standarized. In my case it's better to use `app-name` prop, it's a field from IETF draft draft-ietf-syslog-protocol. I've just replaced

```
property(name="programname")
```

with

```
property(name="app-name")
```

and no more strange program names so far.

Answer (score 1):

From your examples, it seems that in `rsyslogd-2039` the number is the error number. I cannot find where this is documented. You have already found the right answer, to use an alternative field, but for completeness here is how to truncate the programname at the first hyphen (`"-"`). You can use a [property replacer](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html) to select field 1 where fields are delimited by the character with decimal code 45 (ascii hyphen).

```
 %programname:F,45:1%
```